# how to move views quickly from sql server 2008r2 to 2012?

Tags: sql-server, database-migration, data-migration

I am currently on migrating data from sql server 2008r2 to sql server 2012

I have around 100 views on 2008r2 that need to be 'move' to 2012.

The database, tables, schema ... keep the same name.

I am just wondering, rather than copying and pasting those 'views' in sql, is there a more efficient way to create those 100 views on 2012?

Comment: You do know that you can generate a script in `Sql Server Management studio` that includes all the views, right? So you don't have to copy them one by one...

Comment: Find original scripts to create these views, or generate the scripts as @user1429080 said, then run the scripts on new db server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't post comments yet. Here's a simple guide to Generating Scripts from a Database in SSMS.

Right click on the Database you want to move the views FROM in SQL Server Management Studio

***Tasks --> Generate Scripts***

A **Generate and Publish** wizard will appear. In the **Choose Objects** part, select VIEWS. Click Next.

In **Set Scripting Options** you can decide where the script should appear - as a file, in the clipboard, to a new query window. At this point you can click next to end and the script should be generated, however it might be worth noting the ***ADVANCED*** button in **Set Scripting Options**.

The Advanced options allow you to set a lot of things. For example, the default script makes CREATE scripts, but the option Script Drop and Create allows for Drop and Create, Create or Drop only. There are a lot of options in here often overlooked and for a lot of simple database management, especially copying structures or data, it can be helpful to get to know these options.

Comment: thanks  this is exactly what i want, very very useful!!